# How do you create multi layer images using PIL Image.merge

Tags: python, image, merge, python-imaging-library

I want to create a image from multiple bands. It works already if there are exactly 3 input layers(not more not less), but i want to [merge](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image) multiple input bands. It seems the Problem is the [mode](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes). If I type "RGB" for mode it works with 3 bands, but when i try this with more bands I dont know which mode to use. I tried it with different modes but always get the message: "ValueError: wrong number of bands". The question is what do I have to type for mode to make this work.

This works:

```
from PIL import Image

band1 = Image.open("layer1.TIF")
band2 = Image.open("layer2.TIF")
band3 = Image.open("layer3.TIF")

bands = [band1, band2, band3]
multi_layer_img = Image.merge("RGB", bands)
multi_layer_img.save("mli.TIF")
```

but not with more than 3 bands.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? 'L' mode images only have a single band.

Comment: Im tying to create a image with multiple bands like RGB. Im working with remote sensing data and they usually come with 4 or more single bands and i want a program to merge those bands. The output image should be 8 Bit. You are right "L" makes no sense here I will edit my post.

Comment: You're taking a shortcut to merge each of the 3 bands into the R,G,B color parts of a pixel. That trick just won't work with more than 3 bands, because there are only 3 primary colors. You're going to need something *much* more sophisticated.

Comment: You haven't really said what you need to do with the different bands, but I have done some experiments and ImageMagick is able to both read and write and perform sophisticated calculations on multi-layer TIFF files, so that may be something you could explore - either using ImageMagick's Python bindings or shelling out from Python and using the command-line interface.

Comment: I´ve said what i want to do with this - create a multi-layer image by merging or let´s say stacking single bands and thats all. Anyway I solved the problem using numpy and gdal. Thanks for the replys and recommendations.